# How come cell value is not being printed or modified using openpyxl?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

Here is my code. path2 is the path of the new file that is created and being modified.  There are indeed cells inside the .xlsx file that contain "4/1/2017"

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(path2, read_only=False)
ws = wb.active
for row in ws.iter_rows():
    for cell in row:
        if cell.internal_value == "4/1/2017":
            print(cell.value)
            cell.internal_value = endDate          
wb.save(path2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing the cell value against the string `"4/1/2017"`, but it is likely that the cell actually contains a date value that is formatted by Excel to look like `4/1/2017' in the spreadsheet. If the cell actually contains a date, then`openpyxl`will read it as a`datetime` object and you need to test the cell value against a datetime with the correct value.

```
import datetime

if cell.value == datetime.datetime(2017, 4, 1):
    print(cell.value)
```

The `cell.internal_value` for a date is a `float` value, which is the way that Excel stores dates. If you want to test this, you'll need to compare it against the float representation of the date.

If you have a string specifying a date and you can use [`datetime.datetime.strptime()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) to convert the string into a datetime object for comparing with the cell contents.

```
date = datetime.datetime.strptime("4/1/2017", "%m/%d/%Y")
if cell.value == date:
    print(cell.value)
```

Comment: thanks so much! I managed to figure that part out also on my own!

Comment: this is great, but how about if i would also like to mody cells that contain a date range such as 4/1/17-4/31/17, and not only the 4/1/17 cells?  How does one compare to an actual string?

Comment: @Alex I'm not sure what you are asking. Please edit your question with a clear example of the cell contents you are trying to parse.

Comment: What I mean is, is there a way to directly test a value in a cell against a string?

Comment: @Alex If the cell contains a string, then test it against a string. If it contains a date, then test it against a date. If you want to use a string like `"4/1/2017"` to specify a date, then use [`datetime.datetime.strptime()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) to convert the string into a datetime object.

Comment: Great that works! I just used it for my arguments parameters...thank you. What about it if I want to compare against a string like "4/1/17-4/31/17". It does not allow me to do this yet.

Comment: @Alex Are you trying to find out if the cell contains that exact string, or if it contains a date that is between the dates 4/1/17 and 4/31/17?

Comment: if it contains that exact string

Comment: @Alex I've already answered that question: `if cell.value == "4/1/17-4/31/17": print (cell.value)`

Comment: it does not work, i've been trying to figure out why for awhile.